# How to filter out hazardous characters from input coming from xml file in ASp.Net 2.0 c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an xml file with item containing URL with parameter. This parameter will be used in another page and accessed through `Request.QueryString()`.

Doing AppScan, it is found out to be hazardous and need to filter hazardous characters from user input.  How can I do this? Examples of the xml file item with the URL:

```
<item Text="Test" navigate="Test.aspx?Param=TestList" />
```

or

```
<item Text="Test1" navigate="Test1.aspx?Param=TestList;age=5;weight=9" />
```

Any help?

Comment: xml item examples:<item Text="Test" navigate="Test.aspx?Param=TestList" /> OR <item Text="Test1" navigate="Test1.aspx?Param=TestList;age=5;weight=9" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Why do you want to remove special characters? You should escape them (and/or use parameters) instead.

Comment: Could you post the error/warning message you're getting?

Comment: The need arise for the change after the application is scanned for vulnerability and found that the application is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting attacks. The main reason is that it is possible to embed a script in the response.

Comment: You need to write a Regex to do what you want.

Comment: @diamandiev - RegEx makes a good hammer but this question really requires more of a screwdriver. SLaks is on the right path with escaping unfriendly characters.

Comment: @user1118068: You **need** to correctly escape your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is controlled by you (as site owner) and users can't change it than you don't need to filter out anything out of it - just don't put scripts in the XML.

Your actual problem seem to be that pages (like Test.aspx) render query parameter non-escaped (or incorrectly escaped). You should fix this pages as users(hackers) can type in any urls to your site.

I recommend to read on XSS prevention in general. Having very strict list of what query parameters can accept is one of the simplest fixes (i.e. "age" must be integer).